# How to generate/validate unique fractal?

Tags: functions, proof-writing, fractals, cantor-set

There are many known fractals that exist such as Mandelbrot, Cantor set, or the Koch curve, Sierpinski Triangle. What I am curious about, is how one could go about creating their own, unique fractal formula, and more importantly, how to prove that that it is in fact a true fractal.

Comment: I do not know if this could be helpful, but just in case: you can start from something simple, L-Systems have rules that let you generate a fractalic structure, if you follow the rules then the result is a proven fractal structure. You can define which combination of rules you want to apply, so you can create your own L-System fractal. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system